# useEffect function is running but still , not updating the values of states (in react)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, deployment, frontend

```
const [auth, setAuth] = useState();
const verifyAuth = async () => {
    try {
      /* 
      this is working well, when i open it in browser , 
      it gives true when login is successfull , false when 
      i delete the cookie (which is being set by the backend ) 
      but this true and false cant go to setAuth , because useEffect is not working 
      well , auth always giving same value , before and after the cookie added.
      */
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/is_logged_in');
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const data = await verifyAuth();
      console.log('new useEffect');
      setAuth(data);
    })();
  });

  const Handleclick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(auth); // it is always give  same result , before and after login

    if (auth) {
      `your text`;
      console.log('heloo');
    } else {
      navigate('/Login');
    }
  };
```

i have tried several other solutions , as much as i could , some from stack overflow , some from other website , but nothing is working ,   i am stuck in this error since 4 days , plz provide solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect` cannot be `async`. Try this:

```js
const [auth, setAuth] = useState();

const verifyAuth = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/is_logged_in")
    setAuth(res.data)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err) // try to handle error differently (ex: Sentry, etc..)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  verifyAuth()
}, [])
```